# Split a string by space but keep space after reach element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string by space but keep the space after each element. So `'This is a string'` would become `['This ', 'is ', 'a ', 'string']`. The input string could contain words, numbers, or special characters.

Right now I have:

```
var words = text.split(/(\w+\s)/).filter(x => x !== '');
```

The above works, but the regex split gives you `['This ', '', 'is ', '', 'a ', '', 'string']` and requires use of .filter to delete the empty string elements. I bet there is a better regex, but I'm not familiar enough with regex to figure it out.

Comment: To extract all words with trailing whitespaces use `text.match(/\w+\s*/g)`

Comment: [Why would you need this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Because by definition every element except the array's last element has the delimited after it. If you split on space, `"This is a string".split(" ")`, you get `[ "This", "is", "a", "string" ]`. But you are _not_ splitting on space, you're splitting on something [very different](https://regex101.com/r/eeWhTI/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that regex on a string with commas, but neither the comma nor the space after it were kept: `'Hello world, I am a string'` becomes `['Hello ', 'world', 'I ', 'am ', 'a ', 'string']`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am writing a function that wraps text and justifies it. To do this, I am splitting the input into an array (like I've described) then iterating it to test when the character limit of each line has been reached. I did not use .split(' ') because I want to include spaces in my count, and I'm not using a regex that keeps space as a new array element because I also want the space to belong to the word/char/number that preceded it.

Comment: Wait, why do you need spaces for justification? That's literally the thing you're overruling because the spacing needs to become flexible (e.g. you split on space, then you place each word in its own span, typeset them in a flex div with justification on the content, and then you count the number of characters in the actual words and place row breaks accordingly).

Comment: Then use `text.match(/\w+\s*|\W+/g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind as the regular expression to split on, so that the delimiter doesn't use any characters in the string.

```js
const text = 'This is a   string';
const words = text.split(/(?<=\s)/);
console.log(words);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works (and you can remove the `.filter()`)

Comment: Note that if there are multiple spaces between words, they'll each become a separate element in the result. Only the last space is the delimiter.